# How do you prevent pre-installed (unremoveable) Android tasks/apps from ever starting without rooting your phone?

Tags: applications, services, auto-start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop applications and services from running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/how-can-i-stop-applications-and-services-from-running)

Some apps are necessary for notifications. For example, without the facebook process, there'd be no facebook notifications. But other apps, like Qik or Samsung MediaHub, don't need to be running be I don't use them at all whatsoever, and i do not receive notifications from them!!!!

How do I stop that? Not just kill apps, but prevent them from ever starting without rooting?